# How to align caption to the left of a figure?

Tags: floats, captions

I am using this command, but it centers the figure caption. How can I left-align this? Please help me.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{fig1}
\caption{Generation of Digital Signature}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please provide a minimal example of your code, beginning on `\documentclass` and ending in `\end{document`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you want to have the caption at the left corner of the figure, or at the left corner of the page?

Comment: I recommend to use e.g. `\includegraphics[width=Xcm]{example-image}`. This uses an example image provided by latex. Then you don't need to upload your image for the MWE.

Answer (score 12):

You can  load the `caption` package and choose the option `singlelinecheck=off`, and the `measuredfigure` environment from `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage{graphicx, caption} %
\usepackage{threeparttable}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, justification=raggedright, font=footnotesize, labelsep=space}
  \centering
  \begin{measuredfigure} % \begin{measuredfigure}
    \includegraphics{Pepe-le-Pew2}
    \caption{Chuck Jones – Pepe Le Pew in action}
  \end{measuredfigure}
  \label{PlP}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Its work for me. But can you help me more by changing the caption Fig. 1 instead of FIGURE 1: Chunck.....

Comment: Your wish is my command… Please see my modified answer.

Comment: Sorry to say , it did not work.   note:  I am using \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} ( caption aligned to left successfully)

Comment: Just changing the document class in my code works, without having to redefine `\figurename`: `Fig.` is the default in this class. There must be something else in your code.

Comment: Thanks,  finally it works....  You are just awesome.........

Comment: Is there any way to change Fig. 1:  to Fig. 1     actually I want to remove colon from the end

Comment: Yes: you have to use the key `labelsep`. The different possibilities are in the package documentation, § 2.1, *Formatting*, pp.6-7. In my opinion `labelsep=space` doesn't look so nice if there is a caption text (see the updated answer). I would rather choose `period` or `enspace` (the French tradition).

Comment: Why these unnecessary text is added, want to remove please help.....                                                                                              Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin
vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero,
pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet,
tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae
ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla.
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis...

Comment: I used this fake text  to visualise the margins. To remove it, remove all the `\lipsum` commands and the `lipsum` package loading.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [in this answer](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=71074&sid=7e20ca7a6db9f9ee3611fc09a2fd12f7#p71074) on the LaTeX Community forum (LaTeX.org), it's quite easy to achieve the left alignment by loading the package `caption` with the options `singlelinecheck=false` and `justification=justified`:

```
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,justification=justified]{caption}
```

If you're interested in the details, you can read more about this in the `caption` [package documentation](https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) in Sections 2.2 (pp. 9-10).